# Quitar objetos repetidos por un campo en un array

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo el siguiente array

```
const arr = [
{name: pepe, dinero: 40},
{name: jesus, dinero: 50},
{name: pepe, dinero: 30}
]
```

¿Como puedo unir el primer y el tercer objeto en {name:pepe, dinero:70}? Osea, eliminar objeto duplicado por nombre y crear otro igual a la suma de los para al final tener esto:

```
const otroArr = [
{name: pepe, dinero: 70},
{name: jesus, dinero: 50},
]
```

No encuentro metodo en javascript. ¿Podria haber en Lodash algun metodo para hacer esto?. Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Si estas buscando una libreria que lo haga por vos, entonces tengo que cerrar la pregunta.. si queres hacerlo vos, mostra lo que intentaste y podemos ayudarte...

Comment: ok. La edito ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aca va un ejemplo donde podes pasar todos los array que necesites para agrupar por dinero.
En este ejemplo he creado 3 array con nombre y dinero.
Primero punto de observacion comparando con tu JSON object es que los string tipo name en tu caso van cerrado por comillas.

```js
let arr1 = [
        {name: "pepe", dinero: 40},
        {name: "jesus", dinero: 50},
        {name: "pepe", dinero: 30}
    ];
    
    let arr2 = [
        {name: "pepe", dinero: 100},
        {name: "jesus", dinero: 50},
        {name: "maria", dinero: 30}
    ];
    
    let arr3 = [
        {name: "pepe", dinero: 100},
        {name: "Andres", dinero: 500},
        {name: "maria", dinero: 30}
    ];


    function AgruparDinero() {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            arguments[i].forEach(function (el) {
               var item = result.find(function(el1){
                    return el1.name===el.name;
                });
                if (item!==undefined) {
                    item.dinero += el.dinero;
                } else {
                    result.push(el);
                   
                }
            });
        }
        return result;

    }
    
   var nuevoArray = AgruparDinero(arr1, arr2, arr3);
   console.log(nuevoArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta funcion hace lo que pides

```
function acumulate(arr, name){
   // Filtar los objetos con el mismo nombre
   let filtered = arr.filter(item=>{
      return item.name == name;
   });
   // Obtener el valor para el acumulado
   let nValue = 0;
   filtered.forEach(item=>{
      nValue += item.dinero;
   });
   // Crear el nuevo array
   let nArr = arr.filter(item=>{
      return item.name != name;
   });
   // Agregar el acumulado
   nArr.push({name: name, dinero: nValue});
   return nArr;
}
```